# Visual Basic - how to force event to fire

Tags: vba, event-handling

I'm new to VB (using VBA, actually) and I would like to force an event to fire.  Specifically, I am updating the value in a textbox and I would like to call that textbox's AfterUpdate() event.

```
Private Sub cmdCreateInvoice_Click()
  Me.txtInvDate = '11/01/10'
  Me.txtInvDate.AfterUpdate
End Sub
```

During run time, I get an error that says "Compile Error: Invalid Use of Property".  If I try something similar, but with the click event (ex: cmdCreateInvoice.Click), which does NOT have a property that shares the name, I get an error that says "Compile Error: Method or Data member not found".
I know there must be a way to fire one event from another.  But what is the proper syntax?
Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to call your _event handler_ or are you actually wanting to make the text box fire it's event?  The handler, for example, is like the code you posted above; it's the code _you_ write that is executed when that event occurs.

Comment: I want the text box to fire the AfterUpdate event that already exists

Comment: Is this code that you wrote though; like do you have a: `Private Sub txtInvData_AfterUpdate()` that you want to fire?

Comment: yes, I have a procedure written that handles the event (it works when the event is automatically triggered, and I want the same thing to happen when I manually trigger it)

Comment: It is nearly always best in these situations to have a sub that does what you want, and call that sub in both AfterUpdate and the sub above, and anywhere else that it may become necessary.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

AFAIK, there is **no** way to "fire an event manually" in VB(A). What you *can* do is call the *event handler* manually, and for this, rdkleine has given you the answer already:

```
Call txtInvDate_AfterUpdate()
```

This will have exactly the same effect as if the event had fired (though it does *not* give you the whole chain of events that may also fire along with it--unless you `Call` their handlers as well).

IgorM has another valid point, in comments on his answer--it's "cleaner" to write a *different* Sub to do the work you want done, then call it from both the event handler & wherever you're trying to do it now (button click?). So:

```
Private Sub txtInvDate_AfterUpdate()
    DoWhatever
End Sub

Private Sub button_Click()
    DoWhatever
End Sub

Private Sub DoWhatever
    'your desired effect
End Sub
```

You could even make `DoWhatever` a Public Sub in a Module.

**Edit**

And no, in VB(A) it doesn't matter what order you define your Sub (or Function) routines.

Answer (score 3):

Call

> txtInvDate_AfterUpdate()

Comment: why the (nothing, nothing)?  the AfterUpdate sub takes no parameters

Comment: Well, a guess shouldn't qualify as a SO answer.

Comment: It was an educated guess and I corrected the answer. The answer is solid. I don't understand the downvote as the answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use something like this:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_LostFocus()
  TextBox1.Value = "5"
End Sub
```

Use LostFocus event if you change value manually.

Or you can use another way:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
   TextBox1.Value = "new value"
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
   MsgBox TextBox1.Value
End Sub
```

Try to use Change event.

Comment: I need to update the value from within a button's click event (which, incidentally, does a whole bunch of other code that I didn't post).  The point remains the same -- there MUST be a way of firing an event manually

Comment: There is no difference. After updating value in textbox event Change will be called.

Comment: I see what you're saying.  While this may actually solve my current issue, however, it does not help in other instances -- what if I want to call a button's click event, for example?

Comment: Just I think it is not a good idea to call UI events manually. If you need to call Click event then you can create a function and then in Click event you can call this function but also you can call this function whatever you want

Answer (score 0):

Some code apparently will (regretfully) force events to fire:

```
    Me.Dirty = False
```

forces BeforeUpdate and AfterUpdate to fire, as I understand it. There are probably more cases too. Any secret hooks which attach to your code in that manner reflect bad design in my view and will inevitably lead to inadvertant & frustrating loops being created.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a way to keep a textboxes event firing until I click on another text box? I'm needing to stay "in" the text box which has Do While loop for a selection. Once the selection is made, I want the user to be able to replace the selection without having to click on the text box again. If the user is satisfied with the select, they can click on a different text box.