# perl+ VBA: raise click event on a button embedded in a Powerpoint slide

Tags: perl, testing, vba, event-handling, powerpoint

Here I have a powerpoint 2010 presentation. On one slide there is an embedded Windows media Player OCX Control. As a simple GUI, I placed  3 buttons  labeled Play, Pause, Stop on the same slide.

Using Perl's  [Win32::OLE](http://search.cpan.org/~jdb/Win32-OLE-0.1709/) module, I want to test if the click event on "Play" plays the file in the embedded windows media player.

Raising the Click event with the mouse, it does.

Using code below, it does not work. Why?

```
note "Slide $i: " . $slide->{Name};
# switch to "full-screen presentation mode"
PowerpointHelpers::launch_slideshow_from_slide($ole->ActivePresentation, $i);
sleep 3;

#does not work
$btnplay->{OLEFormat}->Object()->btnPlay_Click();

sleep 3;
# return to slide edit-mode
# PowerpointHelpers::exit_show($ole);
```

This is the VBA procedure that is supposed to run:

```
Public Sub btnPlay_Click()

    Init
    PlayVideo (Player.URL)

End Sub
```

As you can see this just calls two custom functions that play an avi file. It does work correctly in interactive use. but not via VBA automation .

Meanwhile, I have tried quite a few variations of the line

```
 $btnplay->{OLEFormat}->Object()->btnPlay_Click();
```

but none work.

Here is a dump of the $btnplay object:

```
OLE object's properties:
Accelerator .............................
AutoSize ................................ 0
BackColor ............................... 8421504
BackStyle ............................... 1
Caption ................................. Video abspielen
Enabled ................................. 1
Font .................................... [IFont]
ForeColor ............................... 0
Height .................................. 28.375
Left .................................... 18.75
Locked .................................. 0
MouseIcon ............................... <undef>
MousePointer ............................ 0
Name .................................... btnPlay
Picture ................................. <undef>
PicturePosition ......................... 7
TakeFocusOnClick ........................ 1
Top ..................................... 382.875
Visible ................................. 1
Width ................................... 124.75
WordWrap ................................ 0
ZOrderPosition .......................... 9
```

Comment: How did you add the ocx file to embed windows media player?

Comment: I added it manually in Powerpoint's edit mode, via the Developer Menu/Controls Ribbon/More Controls  Icon (Click on Hammer-and-Wrench Icon), choosing "Windows Media Player".

Comment: As this is an activex control, you can look at the properties and change the name of it to `mvpDemo` (for example). On the button click, you can write code such as `mvpDemo.controls.pause` or  `mvpDemo.controls.play`. Does that help?

Comment: I don't want to interact with the "native" play/pause/stop buttons of the WMP command bar. They are too small for the touchscreen apllication I am writing. Therefore I have added three much larger Command Buttons. I want to fire the Click events associated with these buttons. Imagine an empty slide with a single CommandButton control, and a simple event handler sub mybotton_Click() "MsgBox 'Hello'" End Sub. I want to call this event handler from perl. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4500335/visual-basic-how-to-force-event-to-fire

Comment: On the click of the bigger buttons, write code such as `mvpDemo.controls.play`? Do you find anything wrong with it? On the other question, isn't it already answered & accepted?

Comment: My VBA function PlayVideo() mentioned above does something similar as you're suggesting. And indeed, the topic of the other question is close to my problem. But I want to do the same thing from Perl Win32::OLE, *and* I must to do this from within a running slide show (note that when I click on the button in edit mode, the button just gets the focus, double click opens the VBA editor etc)

Comment: Having got the handle to the slide, you could call `mySlide.btnPlay_Click` from perl, where `mySlide.btnPlay_Click` is `public`. For e.g. `Application.Presentations(1).Slides(1).btnPlay_Click`

Comment: Pardon my lack of PERL knowledge. You could do `$slide->btnPlay_Click`.

Comment: I've done that, it doesn't work. Please see my own answer to this post, because I cannot really add pretty printed code to this comment, and this thread is already getting too long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works!

```
my $s = $ole->ActivePresentation->SlideShowWindow->View->Slide;

$s->Application->Run('btnPlay_Click', '');
```

Answer (score 0):

**This does not work, it is here for completeness. I was referring to this code in the comments.**

This is my perl code, where I attempt to call the btnPlay_Click event handler directly:

```
my $s = $ole->SlideShowWindows(1)->View->Slide;
PowerpointHelpers::_dump_ole_obj($s, 1);

Win32::OLE->Option(Warn => 3);
$s->btnPlay_Click();  ### DOES NOT WORK (for me)
Win32::OLE->Option(Warn => 0);
```

Error Output of btnPlay_Click();

```
Win32::OLE(0.1709) error 0x80020003: "Member not found"
    in METHOD/PROPERTYGET "" at 06-mediaplayer--button-clicks-ok.t line 127
```

slide object: Output of _dump_ole_obj

```
OLE object's properties:
Application ............................. [_Application]
Background .............................. [ShapeRange]
BackgroundStyle ......................... 0
ColorScheme ............................. [ColorScheme]
Comments ................................ [Comments]
CustomLayout ............................ [CustomLayout]
CustomerData ............................ [CustomerData]
Design .................................. [Design]
DisplayMasterShapes ..................... -1
FollowMasterBackground .................. 0
HasNotesPage ............................ -1
HeadersFooters .......................... [HeadersFooters]
Hyperlinks .............................. [Hyperlinks]
Layout .................................. 1
Master .................................. [_Master]
Name .................................... Slide7
NotesPage ............................... [SlideRange]
Parent .................................. [_Presentation]
PrintSteps .............................. 1
Shapes .................................. [Shapes]
SlideID ................................. 262
SlideIndex .............................. 24
SlideNumber ............................. 24
SlideShowTransition ..................... [SlideShowTransition]
Tags .................................... [Tags]
ThemeColorScheme ........................ [ThemeColorScheme]
TimeLine ................................ [TimeLine]
sectionIndex ............................ 1

More Funcnames:
Cut()
Duplicate()
Export()
GetTypeInfo()
Invoke()
MoveToSectionStart()
QueryInterface()
Release()
SectionNumber()
```